# Issue with regular expressions in dplyr using stri_detect_regex

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I'm running a script that I wrote about six months ago which, until now, has worked perfectly. The data looks something like this:

```
 Speaker       Consonant
  cat              c
  dog              g 
  pig              h
  cat              c
```

And my code should create a new column, 'match', that decides whether there is a match between the speaker and the target consonant:

```
 Speaker       Consonant     Match
  cat              c           T
  dog              g           T
  pig              h           F
  cat              c           T
```

The code I ran previously, using dplyr(), was

```
df %>% mutate(Match = stri_detect_regex(df$Speaker, df$Consonant))
```

Now when I run this I get the following error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
      Evaluation error: Missing closing bracket on a bracket expression. (U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET).
```

Note that my actual code is more complex, with 12 different commands in stri_detect_regex. But it all worked fine previously, and I get this error message even if I just run the first line of the code, as shown in the example code above.

Comment: Do you really need the `df$` there?

Comment: Moreover, it works for me. You know you should do `library(stringi)`

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: I tried it with df$ removed and it still didn't work.

Comment: Looks like an error that has to do with special characters you need to "escape". Do you try to apply the function you posted to the dataset you posted? Or to another bigger daatset?

Comment: Or maybe the version of `stringi` package? You can try updating to the most recent version.

Comment: @AntoniosK probably you are correct. OP Error can be reproduce using `stri_detect_regex("abc[def","[")`. `stri_detect_regex("abc[def","\\[")` will did the trick.

Comment: So, I guess somewhere in the big dataset there's a `[` value in `Consonant` column. Or something like that....

Comment: To be precise there is a **Metacharacters** somewhere in the `Consonant` column.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is the problem! I added some new data (my dataset is much bigger than the example I posted here) and there was a stray [ in there.

Answer (score 1):

I used stringr instead. Seems to work fine.

```
df <- data.frame(Speaker = c("cat", "dog", "pig", "cat"),
                 Consonant = c("c", "g" , "h", "c"))

library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(Match = str_detect(Speaker, Consonant))
```

Update: Your code also works for me with stringi

Comment: This is a much neater version of the code - will change it, thanks!